# Npm global modules destination

Tags: node.js, npm

Where is `npm -g` storing the global modules by default? I am running archlinux.
So if I want to modify a global module where will be the location of it?

Comment: you can check it by `> module.paths` in the node repl.

Comment: with `> module.paths` I am getting this:   `[ '/home/cristian/repl/node_modules',
  '/home/cristian/node_modules',
  '/home/node_modules',
  '/node_modules' ]` But my global modules are not located in none of thouse folders.

Comment: can you post the ouput of the `which node` command? Global installed modules should be in the same directory as the node binaries.

Comment: `/usr/local` it seems: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders Or install a global package, npm will tell you exactly where it was installed.

Comment: I have installed a pachage globally without `sudo` and gave me the error with the path. :)  So the default place where npm is installing packages globally is `/usr/lib/node_modules`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed a package globally without sudo and gave me the error with the path. :) So the default place where npm is installing packages globally is `/usr/lib/node_modules` Thanks guys for your help.